# Lifetime issues with non-copyable owned values when trying to use them after passing them to a function

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I'm running into some problems with lifetime of variables in Rust. The `x` variable in `do_stuff` is borrowed to `try_wrap` and can thus not be returned in the `None` case. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

```
struct NonCopyable;

impl NonCopyable {
    fn new() -> Self {
        NonCopyable
    }
}

fn do_stuff() -> NonCopyable {
    let x = NonCopyable::new();
    match try_wrap(x) {
        Some(val) => val,
        None => x,
    }
}

fn try_wrap(x: NonCopyable) -> Option<NonCopyable> {
    None
}

fn main() {}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:13:17
   |
11 |     match try_wrap(x) {
   |                    - value moved here
12 |         Some(val) => val,
13 |         None => x,
   |                 ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `x` has type `NonCopyable`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you find confusing about the error message? Why do you think that lifetimes have anything to do with the problem? Why do you think borrowing is coming into play here?

Comment: The error message is clear, but I'm having trouble getting around the issue at hand. I guess the best course of action is to move all the logic of the try_wrap method into do_stuff to keep ownership or maybe return the instance inside a tuple with a result value?

Comment: My question is probably confusing because lifetimes relate to borrowed types, not to owned objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with lifetime of variables

There are no lifetimes involved here

> The `x` variable in `do_stuff` is borrowed

No, it is not.

> Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Yes. Borrowing is indicated by an ampersand `&` and/or a lifetime parameter `'foo`:

```
&i32    // a borrowed integer
&'a str // a borrowed string slice with a lifetime
Foo<'b> // a type that contains a borrow of some kind
```

Your `try_wrap` function *takes ownership* of `x`:

```
fn try_wrap(x: NonCopyable) -> Option<NonCopyable>
```

That means `x` is gone and the calling function cannot access it anymore. It has been *moved* into `try_wrap`, which is now free to do whatever it wants with the value, including **destroy it**. That is why the calling function is no longer able to safely access it and why you get the error.

If the type implemented `Copy`, the compiler would have instead implicitly created a copy of the value and passed it in. If the type implemented `Clone`, you could have explicitly called `.clone()` on the argument to `try_wrap` in order to keep the local value.

As [Florian Weimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45255716/155423) notes, you can use a type to return either the wrapped value or the original. It's difficult to tell based on your example, but I disagree with using `Result` **unless it's an error**. Instead, I'd create my own one-off enum or use something like [`Either`](https://crates.io/crates/either):

```
extern crate either;

use either::Either;

fn do_stuff() -> NonCopyable {
    let x = NonCopyable::new();
    match try_wrap(x) {
        Either::Left(val) => val,
        Either::Right(x) => x,
    }
}

fn try_wrap(x: NonCopyable) -> Either<NonCopyable, NonCopyable> {
    Either::Right(x)
}
```

You could also embed the logic of `try_wrap` back into `do_stuff`, or split up `try_wrap` so that the logic doesn't require ownership:

```
fn do_stuff() -> NonCopyable {
    let x = NonCopyable::new();
    if should_wrap(&x) { do_wrap(x) } else { x }
}

fn should_wrap(x: &NonCopyable) -> bool { false }
fn do_wrap(x: NonCopyable) -> NonCopyable { x }
```

Since you are returning the same type, it's also possible you would want to take a mutable reference to the value and just do whatever conditional changes need to happen:

```
fn do_stuff() -> NonCopyable {
    let mut x = NonCopyable::new();
    try_wrap(&mut x);
    x
}

fn try_wrap(x: &mut NonCopyable) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I ended up returning a tuple from `try_wrap` to return ownership.

Comment: @Wouter I'm not sure I understand *how* you are able to do that. A tuple requires all of the members to be present, regardless if it was the success or failure case. If you are doing something like `(Option<Foo>, Option<Foo>)`, that would be a really bad idea because that allows for four possibilities instead of just the two.

Comment: `try_wrap` returns the same type for either case so I can use one field in a tuple to return the wrapped/original object and I can augment the tuple with a boolean to indicate if it was wrapped. https://gist.github.com/wldevries/6d1b3824b26914e114cf257f0a55b963

Answer (score 1):

I think `Option<NonCopyable>` is simply the wrong return type for `try_wrap`.  You need a two-armed sum type here like `Result`, so that the caller can recover the argument in case of an error, perhaps like this:

```
fn do_stuff() -> NonCopyable {
    let x = NonCopyable::new();
    match try_wrap(x) {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(x) => x,
    }
}

fn try_wrap(x: NonCopyable) -> Result<NonCopyable, NonCopyable> {
    Err(x)
}
```